# Running job in hadoop- ERROR security.UserGroupInformation

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I ran a job (jar file) in hadoop , (my jar file has some other jar files and has one zip file.) but i confront with this error. I will be so grateful if anyone can help me and says the reasons of this error. I think this error is beacuse of existing one zip file in my running jar file , but how i can unzip it manually?

```
     ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException
     as:hduser cause:java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.unJar(RunJar.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.downloadCacheObject(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.localizePublicCacheObject(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.getLocalCache(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TaskDistributedCacheManager.setupCache(TaskDistributedCacheManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java:592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:1013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphJob.run(GiraphJob.java:259)
    at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.run(GiraphRunner.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.main(GiraphRunner.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this log:

```
as:hduser cause:java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
```

It seems like you have no permission to read that zip file.

- Please try to read that data by your user? (sudo -u hduser head -l 1 /path/of/file.zip), I guess you will see permission error as well. You should invoke the read permission to your hadoop user (hduser?) first
- Blocked by SELinux is another possible problem, please check log: /var/log/audit/audit.log

If you wanna to unzip that zip file in linux file system, you can run

$ unzip /path/of/file

If this is a hdfs path, you may need to get it first (if I will operate that)

Comment: Thanks. How can I remove specific file inside jar file ?

Comment: @ErfanFarhangy .jar pacakge is a zip file. you can unzip it (using unzip ), remove this file, and rezip (using zip) it, and use .jar as extension. However, I think re-run packaging command from source code is a better solution